# on click of button color is not changed

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have following html code I want to change color of button onclick. I use `$("#submitButton").css("background-color","yellow");`  But it does not change on click.

Here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="docs/assets/css/jqm-docs.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="docsdemos-style-override.css" />


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/main.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

            $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function()
            {
                console.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
                $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
                $.mobile.defaultTransition = 'slideup';
            });

        </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>

</head>
        <body>



        <div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Form Page</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content">   
            <form id="loginForm">

        <!--    Wrap Inputs in fieldcontain which will sort out borders and padding, can cause layout to break  -->
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="firstName"> Username: </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" /> <!--   Use id and name values -->
        </div>  

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="password"> Password: </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" /> <!--   Use id and name values -->
        </div>  

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="dob"> Date of birth: </label>
        <input type="password" name="dob" value="" id="dob" /> <!-- Use id and name values -->
        </div> 


        <div data-role="button">
        <input type="submit" data-role="button" value="Login" id="submitButton">
        </div>

        </form> 
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer content</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->

        </div>  



        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function()
            {
                $('#submitButton').on('click', function(e)
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
                    handleLogin();
                });
            });


        </script>   



        </body>
</html>
```

On click of submit button it call handleLogin() function but color is not changed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's because your form does a `post-back`. If you are handling your login from JS, include a `return false;` line at the end of your button click code.

Comment: I've tidied up your code, but I don't see any link to jquery in the html.

Comment: @ jSang after adding return false doesn't solve issue. Here is my full code

Comment: @PramodD where's `$(document).ready()` :D?

Comment: @jSang $(document).ready() does not support in all mobile platforms therefore I am not using that.  After adding that it works. But I can't use that.

Comment: include this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>` before this line `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>` it might work.

Comment: Vote to close, 'Fix my code' is not a real question.

Comment: @AhsanRathod still no luck after changins sequence.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('#submitButton').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
        handleLogin();
    });
});
```

Prevent the form from refreshing the page, put your code inside document.ready (the `$(function() {..code here..});` ), and remember to include jQuery.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aWTsS/1/)

**EDIT:**

If the new code posted is your entire file, you don't have a handleLogin function (unless it's in an external file) ???

Open the console in your browser (F12) and check if there are any errors.

Comment: handleLogin  function is in different file,not included in same html file.

Comment: Since you're using jQmobile, drop the ready.function and make sure the submit button is'nt duplicated, as that can happen when several pages are loaded in the DOM with ajax, and targeting ID's will no longer work, it's a common JQM problem.

Comment: @ adeneo after trying lot of things only $(document).ready() works. Please llok at my original question I had changes few things again. It is my full html file.

Comment: Well, maybe you need to use some sort of pageinit function, don't now jQuery mobile that well, but there are alternatives to document ready as far as I know. Again, JQM uses ajax to update pages, loading them in the same DOM tree, so duplicated elements from different pages being loaded in the DOM are a common mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Is jQuery included properly?  Because it works for me in my jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jnaHB/

Perhaps the page is refreshing when the request is submitted?

Comment: It's safe to assume `jQuery` is included since `handleLogin()` function is called properly as the OP has stated.

Comment: @jSang: That's true! That didn't occur to me.

Comment: I Like the way you approached the Question and showing it on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You are using a submit button. That's why clicking on submit button it may refreshes the page due to the form submission. You can use the form onSubmit event rather than on button click. And also if you want to see the background color than use "return false;" in your function, otherwise it will again submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

First, you haven't include jquery...

Second, you can add `return false;` in your event callback, otherwise the page will refresh and you won't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

try the code in document.ready

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submitButton').click(function () {
        $("#submitButton").css("background-color", "yellow");

        handleLogin();
    });
 })

Answer (score 0):

Your `$('#submitButton').click(function()` should be inside:

```
$(function() {
  /*Your function*/
})
```

**OR**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/*Your function*/
})
```

**OR**

```
$(window).load(function() {
/*Your function*/
})
```

Comment: I cant use second option. I tried with 1st and 3rd but still not changes color.